# VS2010 javascript debugger wants to launch in new instance of VS2010

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, debugging

When I debug my ASP.NET 4.0 application and it hits the `debugger;` javascript statement it wants to debug that with a new instance of VS2010

> An unhandled exception ('Script Breakpoint') occured in iexplore.exe

How can I make it use the VS2010 that is already open?  I enabled Script debugging in IE11.  Also I enabled Script debugging in VS2010 -Tools - Options - Debugging - 'Just in Time'

Also this worked until recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned on Silverlight debugging applied, and turned it off again.  I think this did the trick, because it works now.